# Is it possible to get literal type from type level into term level in typescript?

Tags: typescript, type-systems

For example, I have this type that will return a type which can only hold one possible value:

```js
  export type IfEqual<T, U> =                                                                               
    (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends                                                                                                        
    (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
```

If I do a declaration like the example below, I can get a value `a` that can only be `true`, and value `b` that can only be `"foo"`.

```js
  declare const a: IfEqual<'a', 'a'>;     // inferred as true                                                                                                              
  declare const b: IfEqual<'a', 'a'> extends true ? "foo" : "bar";  // inferred as "foo"
```

Because there is only one possible value for the type, I wonder if there is anything I can do to turn that type into the corresponding value directly.

Comment: I have hard time to get what you need. But if you need type variable then you can say - `type A = IfEqual<'a', 'a'>` and then `type B = A extends true ? "foo" : "bar" `. But it my only guess that this is what you ask for.

Comment: It's not what I mean. For `declare const a: IfEqual<'a', 'a'>; ` you have `a` with type `true`, so if `a` has any value then it must be true. I wonder if you can make this `true` type into value directly.

Comment: no, you need to make "value constructor" so function which will make the value or just assign it. TS has two levels - type and value. It is not possible to set value by type even though type contains one possible value

Comment: @Ailrk can you explain what you mean by: "extract that value into the term level"?

Comment: @AlexWayne I updated the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

*"I wonder if there is anything I can do to turn that type into the corresponding value directly."*

No.

Typescript only exists at compile time. When the code is compiled and then it is run, all the typing information goes away. Whatever is left, is the javascript that gets run.

In fact if you plug your code into the typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=65#code/AQUwHgDg9gTgLsOBPCJgEkBmBRAjgVwEMAbAHgBUAaYAVQD5gBeYF1t9jzr7n3v4AFAsAFKQDidYQEomDMaDBwQAOwAmAZ2DlgAfmABGYAC5gAJhnglazf1t37DxzyHBRE6bODzLKjbV0GxmYyenAw+GgmmCTqIADc7AICqiAAxsSEMGipUMrqCIQmWHhEZADkhGXUFWV0cclpGVnAOXkIAEZFOAQkpDXVlQw+1ojhaHoARJhQUBNBE+2ZE3FAA) you see that this is the the right hand pane is completely empty. All the types are gone.

Typescript does not do *any* actual logic or computation for you. Instead, it just makes sure that the computation and logic that you do write is correctly using your codebase's types.